# Regexp "and OR or" without repeating expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have text lines that contains:

- mandatory prefix (some constant text e.g. `START`),
- words that must all occur (words `and`) or one word must occur (words `or`),
- mandatory suffix (some constant text e.g. `END`),

There are examples that should be matched:

```
STARTcatdogbirdEND
STARTcatEND
STARTdogEND
STARTbirdEND
```

I can write regexp for `and` (operator `and` that's empty in regexp):

```
START
(?: cat dog bird )
END
```

Also I can write regexp for `or` (operator `|` in regexp):

```
START
(?: cat | dog | bird )
END
```

But how to combine the above without repeating all words (imagine there are long words list or complicated regexp expressions).

Here's working solution (`and` OR `or`), but with repeating expression:

```
START
(?:
 (?: cat dog bird ) | 
 (?: cat | dog | bird )
)
END
```

Online demo: https://regex101.com/r/VRA94J/1

Maybe is there another operator?

```
START
(?: cat magicOperator dog magicOperator bird )
END
```

or possibility reusing a fragment of an expression or another way to write this?

Comment: You can use a positive lookahead to assert the words like `^(?=.*cat)`

Comment: `START(?:(cat)|(dog)|(bird)|(?1)(?2)(?3))END`, see https://regex101.com/r/g6itvb/1